# Creating simple URL's (.htaccess - mod_rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this structure for my navigation index.php?v=page

I am looking to convert it to: www.domain.com/page/ - using mod_rewrite..any ideas on that? I read through some tuts and examples, but couldnt get it working right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some examples.

```
RewriteEngine on

# www.domain.com/page/example changed to index.php?page=example
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

# www.domain.com/example changed to index.php?v=example
RewriteRule ^example(/)?$ index.php?v=example [L]
```

The second rule sounds like what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, i have something like this:
RewriteRule ^features(/)?$ index.php?v=features [L]
RewriteRule ^benefits(/)?$ index.php?v=benefits [L]
RewriteRule ^faq(/)?$ index.php?v=faq [L]
RewriteRule ^pricing(/)?$ index.php?v=pricing [L]
RewriteRule ^get-started(/)?$ index.php?v=get-started [L]

And if I have a couple of sites on one hosting account, this goes in the root dir?

Thank you!

Comment: Does each site have a separate folder or do they point to the same folder? If they point to separate folders then you'll need a .htaccess for each.

Comment: They are in their own folders. I will try that. Thanks

Comment: I have it in its own folder in the directory and when I try going here: http://www.virtualgiftcardsystem.com/features/ - it doesnt load. Any ideas?

Comment: So virtualgiftcardsystem has it's own folder under the root hosting account? You have a .htaccess file in that folder. Silly questions but will ask anyway, you have RewriteEngine on in the .htaccess? Have you check to see that mod_rewrite is installed?

Comment: Correct, its vgc/ within the root directory. I use it for my wordpress installation under the root directory and the rewrite works for WordPress. And again to check, it should be in the vgc/ domain folder. Not the root.

Comment: Try adding "RewriteBase   /" after the line to turn RewriteEngine on, without the " of course.

Comment: http://www.virtualgiftcardsystem.com/features/ - still a 404. I have this now: http://pastie.org/887612 - thanks for your help!

Comment: Try "RewriteBase /vgc/" - vgc being the name of the sub folder

Comment: Same thing, and I checked to make sure GoDaddy allows mod_rewrite and they do. Not sure why it isnt working! Thank you

Comment: how about what is suggested here? http://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy